# Android ListView partial pressable areas

Tags: android, listview, touch

I would like to create a ListView item layout where I can touch certain portions of a line item. This is similar to the behavior of the 2.0's Contacts Call Log where I can click on the green phone logo to initiate a call or click on the incoming call details to get more information about the contact.

I don't need a behavior only implementation. I already know to bind OnClickListeners to the portions of the line items where I want to capture the press. My real issue is that the UI doesn't react properly in certain cases when a user press against a certain area of the screen. IE: if they clicked the green phone icon, only the box around the phone will highlight as pressed. Where as pressing the name will highlight that area.

I looked at the source code for the contacts app but it's very complicated and I was able to get some success I have issues where the source code is referencing Drawables and resources that aren't exposed in the SDK itself.

I would like a reasonable implementation that does not rely on internal resource of android. Or at least some pointers in the right direction.

I'm looking for a solution that works with not only pressing but the 5-way directional keypad as well.

Here's a graphic that shows what I'm talking about.

[image: Android Call Log]
<sub>(source: [the-gadgeteer.com](http://the-gadgeteer.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/and_cupcake_call-log1-200x300.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just looks like [when setting up each list row](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/contacts/RecentCallsListActivity.java;h=54e9a05a471c4fad8233d902d325d41a3fd92178;hb=donut#l380) in the `newView` method they set an `onClickListener` for the green `call_icon`.  While binding the view the telephone number is added to the `call_icon` by way of the `View.setTag()` method.

Then, in the [`onClick` handler](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/contacts/RecentCallsListActivity.java;h=54e9a05a471c4fad8233d902d325d41a3fd92178;hb=donut#l191), the phone number gets pulled and the phone call `Intent` is fired.

All other presses on the list row get handled by the usual way — the `onListItemClick` method.

Comment: I have the behavior working fine. I do use the tag to determine how to operate and bind the OnClickListeners properly. The issue is that I cannot get the yellow-orangeish background to appear when the user presses against the widget properly in all cases. Particularly when they use the 5-key directional pad the text goes black as expected but the background stays black.